# how to get record of immageable type by id in laravel morph relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

For the Messaging system, I have setup two morph relationships using four tables.

My questions are?

1. How can I get from a specific Student's message from **receives collection**?

For example, if **Student X and Y** send messages to **Staff A**

when I query Staff A's received messages like:

```
$staff = \App\Staff::find(1);
$all_message_recieves = $staff->receives;
```

I got both messages from **Student X and Y**, but I want only the **Student X** messages

Tables structure are

```
tbl_message

id messageable_id, messageable_type, subject, message

1     1              app\staff        msg1     msg1
2     2              app\staff        msg1     msg1
3     1              app\student      msg2     msg2
4     2              app\student      msg2     msg2
```

```
tbl_message_receiver

id, message_id , receiveable_id, receiveable_type

1     1            1                 app\student
2     2            2                 app\student
3     3            1                 app\staff
3     4            1                 app\staff
```

```
Staff

id name
1   A
2   B
```

```
Student

id name
1   X
2   Y
```

Message.php model

```
class Message extends Model
{

    public $table = "tbl_message";

    public function messageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

**Messagereceive.php model**

```
class Messagereceive extends Model
{
    public $table = "tbl_message_receiver";
    public function receiveable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function message()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('App\Message');
    }
}
```

**Staff.php model**

```
class Staff extends Model
{

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Message', 'messageable');
    }

    public function receives()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Messagereceive', 'receiveable');
    }
}
```

**Student.php model**

```
class Student extends Model
{

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Message', 'messageable');
    }


    public function receives()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Messagereceive', 'receiveable');
    }
}
```

Comment: pluck your code a bit and be more organized when u ask questions.

Comment: sorry for the unorganized question, I just didn't understand how to ask questions in laravel, I am newbie to laravel